# String formatting with argument from multiple return value function

Tags: python, string-formatting

How can I use functions that return multiple values as inputs to a format string, without getting the `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string` error?

```
>>> def foo():
...     return 1, 2
... 
>>> foo()
(1, 2)
>>> print "%d,%d,%d" % foo(), 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Expected output: "1,2,3"

Comment: `print "%d,%d,%d" % (foo() + (3,))` should do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Element index

`string.format()` is more powerful and lets you [access list elements or even attributes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#grammar-token-element_index):

```
>>> print "{0[0]},{0[1]},{1}".format(foo(), 3)
1,2,3
```

#### Concatenate tuple

The problem with `foo(), 3` is that it's a tuple and an integer, two different types. Instead you can create a 3-tuple via concatenation. If you use `string.format()` it's a bit trickier, as you need to unpack it first using the `*` operator so you can use it as arguments:

```
>>> foo() + (3,)
(1, 2, 3)

>>> print "%d,%d,%d" % (foo() + (3,))
1,2,3

>>> print "{},{},{}".format(*foo() + (3,))
1,2,3
```

#### Temporary variables

Of course, you can always do it this way, which is obvious but verbose:

```
>>> foo1, foo2 = foo()
>>> print "%d,%d,%d" % (foo1, foo2, 3)
1,2,3
```

Comment: Ouch! I didn't reallize you already had `(foo() + (3,))` in your answer. :/

Answer (score 2):

The reason `print "%d,%d,%d" % foo(), 3` is not working is because Python is thinking you're trying to print two items here: `"%d,%d,%d" % foo()` and then `3`. Due to this the first expression clearly fails because of in-sufficient number of items:

```
>>> def func():
...     print "%d,%d,%d" % foo(), 3
...     
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(func)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('%d,%d,%d')
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (foo)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              9 BINARY_MODULO       
             10 PRINT_ITEM          
             11 LOAD_CONST               2 (3)
             14 PRINT_ITEM          
             15 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

In fact even something like `"%d,%d,%d" % foo() + (3,)` won't work because I guess [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) comes into play here:

```
>>> def func():
    print "%d,%d,%d" % foo() + (3,)
...     
>>> dis.dis(func)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('%d,%d,%d')
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (foo)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              9 BINARY_MODULO       
             10 LOAD_CONST               3 ((3,))
             13 BINARY_ADD          
             14 PRINT_ITEM          
             15 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

A working version will be:

```
>>> print "%d,%d,%d" % (foo() + (3,))
1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

A general solution to take an arbitrary number of arguments and print them with some delimiter would be to use `str.join`

```
def foo():
    return 1, 2

>>> print(','.join(map(str,foo())))
1,2
```

Another example

```
def bar():
    return 4,5,6,7

>>> print(','.join(map(str,bar())))
4,5,6,7
```